# Slideshow with images and videos

Tags: android, slideshow, android-videoview, viewflipper

I need to implement a slideshow with images and videos. The slideshow must play automatically. When a video is displayed, the slideshow stops sliding, video start playing and when video has finished the slideshow starts sliding again with next views. 
I tried to implement this using `ViewFlipper`, but I have problems with videos. My question is : there are others ways to make this (without `ViewFlipper`) ? Has anyone made something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have this slideshow functionality using **ViewPager** in Android, when there is any video in ViewPager then stop flipping view pager and play video and onCompletionListener you should play slideshow again